# Unable to configure wifi on Packard Bell Dot S

Tags: wifi, broadcom, puppy-linux

A few hours ago I installed Puppy Linux on to the quoted machine and have been pulling my hair out trying to configure the wifi.

Reasonably sure my machine needs the broadcom driver/pack but have no clue how to fix it.

I've laboriously looked through previous posts but the only solutions i could find used shell commands not available in Puppy.

Please help before this netbook goes out the window.

Comment: Puppy should go out of the window.

Comment: I'm thinking lubuntu instead? booted it from a usb and it instantly configured my wireless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your desktop clic **connect**

[image]

Next step clic **Load module**

[image]

Choose `b43` or `b43-legacy` then press **Load**

If the tow modules doesn't work , you can choose **Ndiswrapper**  then select the `.inf`  file (of the windows driver)

Comment: Thanks, I gave up and went with lubuntu but it might help someone else. I was pretty sure i tried every module there was (the ones mentioned included) plus tried the wrapper but might have had the wrong driver